# Mailchimp api not sending goodbye email -with https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

when unsubscribing an user I want de default Mailchimp goodbye email to be send.

I'm using the following code

```
$mailchimp = new MailChimp($apiKey);

$md5 = md5($_POST['email']);

$result = $mailchimp->put("lists/$listId/members/$md5", [
    'status'        => 'unsubscribed',
    'send_goodbye'  => true
]);
```

I have the "Send unsubscribe confirmations to subscribers" check in the relevant list.

It unsubscribes the user but never sends the email.
Any idea why?

I'm using the following php wrapper:
https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api

Thanks